# SQL several characteristics query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my SQL query. I have operations with (specific ID for each one) and I have participants in those operations that can be (seller, facilitator, manager, assistant)

Table looks like:

```
ID    Volume   Participant
---------------------------
122   100      Sellers
122   100      Facilitator
123    50      Sellers
123    50      Manager
123    50      Facilitator
124   120      Sellers
124   120      Assistant
125   180      Manager
125   180      Sellers
125   180      Facilitator
```

I want to extract operations where, for example, seller and manager have participated. In this case, the seller and manager have participated in operations 123 and 125

```
SELECT ops.opsId, ops.opsvolume, tranche.participant
FROM ops 
INNER JOIN tranche ON ops.opsID = tranche.opsId
WHERE tranche.participant = 'seller' 
  AND tranche.participant = 'manager'
```

But obviously the participants can not be two roles at the same time, it is the operation that has several roles, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to include ALL the records for IDs the meet the requirements? IE, do you want to include the `(123, 50, Facilitor)` row for ID 123?

Comment: That would be great

Comment: does the table have a PK? Can there be a Participant more than once per ID?

Comment: There are two tables, table ops and table tranche, the union of both results in the mentioned table, (both tables have PK). Now the question is how can I filter those results to get only the operations where they have worked (sellers and managers) in the same deal

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in the question yet to fully answer it. But perhaps you can start with this:

```
SELECT * FROM ops WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM ops
    WHERE participant IN ('sellers', 'manager')
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by pivoting out new columns, after which you can simply use a WHERE clause

```
with q as
(
  SELECT ops.opsId, 
       max(ops.opsvolume) Volume, 
       max(case when tranche.Participant = 'seller' then 1 else 0 end) HasSeller,
       max(case when tranche.Participant = 'manager' then 1 else 0 end) HasManager
  FROM ops 
  INNER JOIN tranche ON ops.opsID = tranche.opsId
  GROUP BY ops.opsId
)
select opsId, Volume
from q
where HasSeller = 1 
 and  HasManager = 1
```